# Computing the distribution of a uniform r.v. with parameter being another uniform r.v.

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have this:

> Let $X\sim U(0,1)$, $Y\sim U(X,1)$.
>   What is the distribution of variable $Y$?

My answer: I use a geometric approach since everything happens in the square $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, see the image.

[image]

so I found that

$$F(y)= \mathbb{P}\{ Y \leq y \}=
\begin{cases}
0 & y<0 \\
y^2 & 0 \leq y\leq 1\\
1 & y>1
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$f(y)=
\begin{cases}2y & 0\leq y\leq 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Is this approach correct?

Comment: To address more directly the reason why your approach fails... Note that if $(X,Y)$ was uniformly distributed in the triangle $T=\{(x,y)\mid 0<x<y<1\}$ (the one you draw in your picture), then the PDF of $X$ would be $2(1-x)$ on the interval $(0,1)$. Instead, one is given that $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$. Thus, your mistake is to assume that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in $T$. (The PDF of $(X,Y)$ is actually $\frac1{1-x}$ on $T$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A sanity check:** verify you get the right expectation. (This is not sufficient, but at least it's a necessary condition for correctness).

Since $Y\sim U(X,1)$, [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Moments)
$$\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = \frac{1}{2}(1+X)$$
and therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]] = \frac{1}{2}(1+\mathbb{E}[X])
= \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{3}{4}$$
since $X\sim U(0,1)$ (for the second-to-last equality).

Your solution, however, yields
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy f(y)y=\int_{0}^1 2y^2dy = \frac{2y^3}{3}\Big|_0^1=\frac{2}{3}
$$
so **your answer cannot be correct.**

---

**A derivation:**

Fix any $t\in\mathbb{R}$. First of all, it is obvious that $F_Y(t) = 0$ if $t\leq 0$ and $F_Y(t) = 1$ if $t\geq 1$, so we can focus on $t\in(0,1)$. Then, we have
$$
F_Y(t) = \int_0^1 dx \int_x^t dy \frac{1}{1-x}\mathbb{1}_{\{t\geq x\}}
= \int_0^t dx \int_x^t dy \frac{1}{1-x}
= \int_0^t dx \frac{t-x}{1-x}
$$
and after computation, we get
$$
F_Y(t) = \begin{cases} 0 &t\leq 0\\
t+(1-t)\ln(1-t) & t\in(0,1)\\
1 & t\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
(which after verification is consistent: $F_Y(0^+)=0, F_Y(1^-)=1$, and $F_Y$ is non-decreasing and continuous.)

Deriving this CDF, we obtain
$$
f_Y(t) = -\ln(1-t) \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(t),\qquad t\in\mathbb{R}
$$
which passes the (necessary) test
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty t f_Y(t) dt = -\int_0^1 t\ln(1-t) dt = \frac{3}{4}.
$$

---

**Plot of the results obtained in the derivation:**

[image: PDF $f_Y$ of $Y$]

PDF $f_Y$ of $Y$

[image: CDF $F_Y$ of $Y$]

CDF $F_Y$ of $Y$

Comment: Note: For the derivation, I was tempted to use the characteristic function (with conditioning), but ended up with special functions to express $\mathbb{E}[e^{itY}]$. If there is an elegant solution of that sort, I'd welcome it.

Comment: Re the characteristic functions approach, note that the conditional PDF of $Y$ yields $$E(e^{itY}\mid X)=\int_X^1\frac{e^{ity}}{1-X}dy=\frac{e^{it}-e^{itX}}{it(1-X)},$$ and that $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, hence $$E(e^{itY})=\int_0^1\frac{e^{it}-e^{itx}}{it(1-x)}dx.$$ Integrating by parts with $$u(x)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{itx}}{it},\quad v'(x)=\frac1{1-x},\quad u'(x)=-e^{itx},\quad v(x)=-\log(1-x),$$ this is $$E(e^{itY})=\int_0^1e^{itx}(-\log(1-x))dx,$$ which proves your claim that the PDF of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=-\log(1-y)$ on $0<y<1$. (The trick is to avoid computing explicitely $E(e^{itY})$.)

Comment: @Did Oh, I see. Thanks! Yes, I attempted to compute explicitly the integral of the second equation. It did not make my day.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.I was so confused.Thank you for your help again

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: One last thing..What's the theory behind the double integral?How we get these limits of integration?

Comment: It's basically integrating the pdf of (X,Y), using the fact that f(x,y)=f(x)f(y|x) (these notations are a bit sketchy, but that's the gist of it).

Comment: So the distribution of Y is in fact the joint PDF of (X,Y)?

Comment: Not exactly. The distribution of Y is a well-defined something: it is what it is. But it's much easier to figure out what it is using X as a "proxy." I.e., with the same sketchy notations, $f (y)=\int dx f(x,y)$.